# Как правильно связать 3 модели в Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Господа и дамы.
Есть модель `Foods`, которая содержит в себе рецепты блюд.
Есть модель `FoodStuff`, которая содержит в себе продукты и их характеристики.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, каким образом будет правильно связать данные модели, если:

1. Блюдо(Foods) может состоять из нескольких продуктов(FoodStuff);
2. Не хочется создавать поле ForeignKey прямо в продуктах(Foodstuff), ибо будет куча лишней инфы в базе данных (типо куча дублей названий продуктов и их характеристик).

**models.py**

```
class Foods(models.Model):
    """Блюда"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Foods name')
    rusname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Русское название')

class FoodStuff(models.Model):
    """Продукты и их характеристики"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Foodstuff name')
    rusname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Русское название')
    protein = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Белки')
    fat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Жиры')
    carbohydrates = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Углеводы')
    kkal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Количество килокалорий на 100г')

class FoodsIngridients(models.Model):
    """Ингридиенты блюд из Foods"""
    ingridient = models.IntegerField(choices=[i.id, i.rusname for i in FoodStuff.objects.all()], verbose_name='Ингридиент')
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Количество ингридиента')
    foods_ing = models.ForeignKey(Foods, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foods_ingridients')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("ingridient", "foods_ing"))
```

Пока что добавил дополнительную модель FoodsIngridients, в которую записываются ингридиент и его количество - для каждого блюда. Конструкция `choices=[i.id, i.rusname for i in FoodStuff.objects.all()]` призвана добавить список для выбора продукта и добавления его id в таблицу FoodsIngridients.

Так вот, очевидно, что всё это выглядит стрёмно и к тому же айдишники ингридиентов из FoodsIngridients связаны только с блюдами(Foods), а с продуктами(Foodstuff) не связаны никак.

Уважаемые душители змия-питона, объясните, как правильно реализовать данную связь моделей. А также, как затем я смогу вытащить из базы блюда по ингридиентам (например, на вход даны строковые значения "Соль", "Картошка")?

Буду вам очень признателен :)

Comment: Т.е. требования какие? Блюдо может состоять из нескольких продуктов, а продукты могут исползьоваться в приготовлении многих блюд? Вам показана связь many-to-many. Посмотрите, что такое ManyToManyField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/, это оно?

Comment: @mrEvgenX А можете подсказать насчёт поля `quantity` - количество ингридиента в конкретном блюде. Как я понял из документации, необходимо создать промежуточную модель с данным полем и ForeignKey к модели Foods ?

Comment: а где можно посмотреть код Вашего проекта? может на гитхаб ссылка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ManyToManyField` задействует промежуточную модель, которая создается автоматически, ее мы у себя в коде даже не заметим, она состоит из двух полей, первое является внешним ключом на одну модель, второе - внезапно, на вторую. Таким образом каждая строка в этой промежуточной модели задает связь одного с другим.

Эту промежуточную модель можно задать явно с целью добавить характеристики этой связи.

Пусть у нас есть 2 сущности, которые мы хотим связать отношением "многие-ко-многим". Сами классы рекомендовал бы называть в единственном числе, так как это класс для экземпляра описываемой сущности в количестве одна штука. Ненужные для демонстрации поля убраны, а имена заменены на более подходящие в субъективном смысле.

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CookingProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Если мы мы в `class CookingProduct` добавим строчку

```
    needed_for_dishes = ManyToManyField(to=Dish)
```

То неявно создастся модель с двумя внешними ключами, как говорилось выше и только. Но нам нужно же еще учитывать параметры этой связи.

Для учета `quantity` создаем нашего посредника же явно.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    # Нам обязательно потребуется внешний ключ на одну модель
    dish = models.ForeignKey(to=Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # И на вторую
    cooking_product = models.ForeignKey(to=CookingProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Затем размещаем наши данные
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

А строчка с заданием связи будет выглядеть так

```
    needed_for_dishes = ManyToManyField(to=Dish, through='Ingredient')
    # through - строка, потому что класс Ingredient еще не объявлен, но сослаться на него надо
```

Вот и полноценная связь. Рекомендую изучать [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/), а если английский не на уровне, то пользоваться переводчиками сайтов. На сайте есть пошаговый туториал, как делается приложение на Django, в котором разбираются довольно-таки типовые приемы написания кода, которые пригодятся и потом. А еще заходим на ютуб и вводим "Пишем приложение на django с нуля" и получаем тонны годных скринкастов, которые стоит пройти до конца и узнать много нового.